# How to Extract Viewport Specific CSS?

Tags: css, responsive-design, viewport, viewport-units

I am trying to optimize speed of my existing wesite. I want to remove unused css for each viewport. The website has media-queries in main css. I want to extract / create css file which will contain only those css (selectors /properties) that are used in specific viewport.

I have searched about this but haven't found any perfect solution.

Is there any tool? Webpack etc or doing it manually is the only solution.

Thanks

Comment: Just curious, what will happen when the user changes viewport dimensions?

Comment: The design will be resposive between two viewports. If the website is loaded in 600px and next break-point is 400px then css for 600px will be loaded and it will be responsive till 400px @A Haworth.

Comment: Also, this is not about critical-css so i am not considering height of the device. So 600px and 400px are width

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are services like https://github.com/uncss/uncss, https://www.purgecss.com/ or https://unused-css.com/

Or you can also use Chrome Dev Tools.

- Open web inspector
- Open the command menu. For me it's `Command + Shift + p`, not sure if it's the same for all operating systems
- Search for then select 'show coverage'
- look for the coverage tab. You may need to reload the page to see the results.

Remember that all of these options check just the one page, so don't assume that code not used on one page isn't used on another without checking first.

Comment: I have used / checked many serivces. Unused-css will not work here. I guess purgecss with postcss will work. I will check and update. Thanks @David